# How to run code on Android Tablet from Ubuntu connected via USB?

Tags: android, c

I am trying to run a C code on an Android tablet from my computer which has Ubuntu 12.04. But when I run the application on android the tablet is not getting detected.

Please help me as to what to do.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. An android tablet doesn't natively run "a C code". Can you explain what you try to do, and how you suppose this should work? You can look into the Android NDK to incorporate code into an APK, but I don't think this is wat you are looking for.

Comment: @Nanne ok basically m trying to connect a tablet pc to my computer which has Ubuntu 12.04, when i run the ndk code on android application it showing me the following error ???????????? no permissions
on the android device part

Comment: This is important information: please add it to your question (so add what you try to do, EXACTLY how you try to do it, and the exact error you get.)

Comment: @Nanne thnx but i resolved it.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you did add some information to the question, and answered it yourself. It helps future googlers/AU-ers, and will give you some more reputation here as well.

Comment: @Nanne yeah thnx for that.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html).

adb is run from the terminal, and allows you to run shell commands on the phone. You could write C code which executes adb via [system()](http://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/).

It might be easier to just write a [shell script](http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial).

Comment: My system which has Ubuntu 12.04 on it, even though it was detecting a Tablet PC via usb cable but it was unable to run my application on it since usb driver was not set properly. When i changed the .rules from /etc/udev/rules.d its working well now. I did the following update in the 70-persistent-cd.rules SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev".

Comment: After doing this close the file and restart the service as follow sudo service udev restart